# Adjust local space scale to fit object size

Tags: modeling, scale, units, object-mode, measurement

I have an I-carrier that I want to have in a certain dimension. I thought about scaling the thing in object mode and then applying the scale. However when I do that, the size of the object in the x-direction seems to be off as it doesn't match what I'm typing in the transform window.

My best bet is that this is because the local space of the object doesn't match the object size, at least in the x-direction. So how can I adjust my local space so that the adjustments I make in the transform window correctly translate to the objects dimension?

[image: I-beam that should have certain dimensions]

Note: Even after applying the scale, the objects dimensions are way off. However, the dimensions in the edit mode are right.